# node-react javascript application- how to have special characters(symbols) as inputs in html

Tags: javascript, html, special-characters, symbols

I'm currently building an online webpage using the league API. Currently it only takes in the English language and characters. Is there a way I could take in symbols and other languages as an input and give back the result?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can, using a markdown editor. Here are some Reactjs examples
https://reactjsexample.com/tag/markdown/